# Excel VBA "If" statement Error

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

So I'm getting an error with some code and I don't know how to get around it

```
Range("K" & varOffset).Select
           Output = If (ISBLANK(H2), "No", "Yes")      <----------Shows up red
           ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Output`
```

How do I make this if statement work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

Formulae in Excel is not VBA. VBA has its code structure that needs to be adherered to

```
Range("K" & varOffset).Select
If trim(Range("H2")) = "" then 
  output = "No"
else 
  output =  "Yes"
end if
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Output
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped a lot! However, I realized I made a huge mistake in my question, I actually want it to check two cells to the left of the current cell (Instead of always H2). I also want it to update when I change that information, as of right now the cell stays as "yes" or "no" regardless of whether H2 has changed. Would this be possible?

Comment: So I figured out how to make the offset, but need it to update when I add information in.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to use the worksheet version of IF.

Try VBA IF block

```
If IsEmpty(H2) Then
    Output = "No"
Else
    Output = "Yes"
End If
```

Comment: So I also want it to update when I change "H2" in the sheet after I do the macro, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

the below will avoid the need to select a cell which should always be avoided. It also avoids the need for the output variable

```
with Range("K" & varOffset)
    If trim(Range("K" & varOffset).offset(0,-2).value)="" then'If blank
        .value= "Yes"
    else
        .value= "No"
    endif
end with
```

Comment: So I made a mistake. I actually want it to compare 2 cell to the left of the current cell.